# Need help in building a decode statement in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a Oracle query which I need to convert to bigquery query and need help, I am lost as to how to convert it below is my oracle code

> decode(to_char(c.last_updated_time  +3, 'D') ,7 , c.last_updated_time
> +5 ,1 ,c.last_updated_time  +5, 2, c.last_updated_time  +5,3, c.last_updated_time  +4, c.last_updated_time  +3) FollowUP

I need the same to be convert in bigquery query any help would be appriciated

Comment: Can you explain the logic that the query is implementing in English? I think it's if the date is Saturday, Sunday or Monday add 5 days; Tuesday add 4 days else add 3 days but the days of the week might be out by one or two days (depending on where you are in the world) What is the value of `SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_TERRITORY';` and do you just have a single user or do you have users connecting from around the world (it makes a difference as `TO_CHAR(date_value, 'D')` will give different answers depending on where the database thinks you are in the world)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%u', DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY)) = '6' THEN DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%u', DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY)) = '7' THEN DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%u', DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY)) = '1' THEN DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%u', DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY)) = '2' THEN DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 4 DAY)
    ELSE DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY)
  END
```

see below example - you can use it for testing

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS last_updated_time
)
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%u', DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY)) = '6' THEN DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%u', DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY)) = '7' THEN DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%u', DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY)) = '1' THEN DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%u', DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY)) = '2' THEN DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 4 DAY)
    ELSE DATE_ADD(c.last_updated_time, INTERVAL 3 DAY)
  END
FROM data AS c
```

Comment: In Oracle, `to_char(date_value, 'D')` returns different values depending on the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting for the user's session. If the user running the query is in most European countries then a date on Monday returns `1`; if the user is in America then Sunday dates return `1`; if the user is in the Middle-East then Saturday dates return `1` and if the user is in Bangladesh then Friday dates return `1`. I'm not sure where the OP is in the world or whether they have users running their query in different territories but you may need to convert that behaviour as well.

Comment: sure. agree. I tried to help OP to get moving in what I think right (or at least reasonable) direction :o)